# Git diff chunks

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I am learning about the git diff command. I am not familiar with the built in diff tool that is part of terminal. From what I have read about the git diff command online, it will only output the differences between the current file in the git staging area (index) and the working directory. However, when I run the git diff command, I get an output with all the lines - both edited and unedited lines- in my file. This gets me confused about the whole git diff chunks. I understand what the change markers and label headers in the git diff output are and what they do, but I am just confused about the diff chunks.

[Original file (file in staging area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7l85.png)

[Edited file (file in working directory)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCMe0.png)

[Terminal with git diff output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKrzj.png)

Comment: The added lines are prefixed with a `+`, removed lines with a `-`. All other lines are here to present a bit of context. But what is the question, Ibrahim?

Comment: So the diff output includes unedited parts of the file?

Answer (score 1):

The diff format Git uses is a variant of the format known as the *unified diff format*.  This format has some headers, including the line numbers of the hunk before and after the change, and each hunk contains lines starting with `+` if they are additions, `-` if they are removals, or a space if they are the lines of context around this change (by default, three lines on each side).  All modifications to a line in this format are expressed as additions and removals.

The context lines are useful because diffs are often applied as patches to a piece of source code.  For example, the Git project submits changes by sending specially formatted patches to a mailing list.  Because diffs may be applied to a different version than they were originally created from, the context is used to (a) inform the reviewer about the data nearby to help ease review and (b) to help the patch application machinery find the proper segment of code to which to apply the changes.

It is possible to adjust the amount of context provided in some cases to aid in review or address situations where three lines of context isn't sufficient to identify the proper location for application.

So, to answer your question, yes, the context in the diff hunks is essentially unedited parts of the file.